# How to data pass array to dictionary in Alamofire

Tags: swift, swift3

my json response array to dictioary but i am tring to get my data in show tableview.but my response in one key "member" and i want get data for a member key but getting some error.

I am trying to pass an array as a parameter to a Alamofier request .but i have not get data from my json i am getting some error my code i can not what i do....

My URL:

```
https://myfoodtalk.com:3001/api/restaurants?filter={"counts":"restaurant-comments","order":"created DESC","include":[{"relation":"follow-restaurants","scope":{"where":{"m_id":""}}},{"relation":"members"},{"relation":"favorite-restaurants","scope":{"where":{"m_id":""}}}]}
```

My model class:

```
class RestaurantsData: NSObject {
    var title = String()
    var descriptions = String()
    var image1 = String()
    var postcommentsCount = String()
    var viewscount = String()
    var created = String()
    var members = [String:Any]()
    var mbersdata = membersData()
    func getRestaurentData(dataArray: [[String:Any]]) -> [RestaurantsData] {
        var array = [RestaurantsData]()
        let mObj = membersData()

        for item in dataArray {
            let obj = RestaurantsData()
            obj.title = item.validatedValue("title", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.descriptions = item.validatedValue("description", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.image1 = item.validatedValue("image1", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.postcommentsCount = item.validatedValue("post-commentsCount", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.viewscount = item.validatedValue("views_count", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.created = item.validatedValue("created", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.members = item.validatedValue("members", expected: [String:Any]() as AnyObject) as! [String:Any]
            obj.mbersdata =   mObj.getMemberData(dataDic:obj.members)
            array.append(obj)
        }
        return array
    }
    //Mark:- Class created for member data

    class membersData: NSObject {
        var photo = String()
        var created = String()
        var username = String()
        func getMemberData(dataDic: [String:Any]) -> membersData {
            let obj = membersData()

            obj.username = dataDic.validatedValue("username", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.created = dataDic.validatedValue("created", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String
            obj.photo = dataDic.validatedValue("photo", expected: String() as AnyObject) as! String

            return obj

        }
    }
}
```

My code:- I'm using Alamofire

```
 var dataArray = [RestaurantsData]()

   //MARK: Web API calling
   func ShowRestaurantsData(){

      var params = [String:Any]
            params = [
                "counts":"restaurant-comments",
                "order":"created DESC",
                "include":[["relation":"follow-restaurants","scope":["where":["m_id":""]]],["relation":"members"],["relation":"favorite-restaurants","scope":["where":["m_id":""]]]

      Alamofire.request( "https://myfoodtalk.com:3001/api/restaurants", method:.get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
                switch responseObject.result
                {
                case .success(let value):
                    let dataArray = value as! [[String:Any]]
                    print("JSON Response:::::: \(dataArray)")

                    let obj = RestaurantsData()
                    self.dataArray = obj.getRestaurentData(dataArray: dataArray)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to correct its formatting. The `code` format should only be placed around *code*, with any comments written in *as code comments* so that the whole thing can be copy-pasted and run as-is. The code inside `code` formatting should be indented correctly. The more work you put into asking a question that's easy to read and understand, the more likely it will be that someone will be able to help you :)

Comment: change let dataArray = value as! [[String:Any]] to let dataArray = value as? [String:Any]

Comment: hi sir, i am change  let dataArray = value as! [[String:Any]] to let dataArray = value as? [String:Any] but not working getting error nil value

Answer (score 2):

In your request,

```
Alamofire.request( "https://myfoodtalk.com:3001/api/restaurants", method:.get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { (responseObject) -> Void in
```

You are passing "

> parameters as nil

which is wrong, pass "params"...